# What is the size of $\text {Aut}\ (C)\ $?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, automorphism-group, graph-isomorphism

> Consider the graph $C$

[image]

How do I find the size of $\text {Aut}\ (C)\ $?

Since each of the vertices has $3$ neighbouring points so $\text {Aut}\ (C)$ acts transitively on the set of all vertices of the graph $C.$ Let us fix some element say $1 \in V_C,$ where $V_C$ is the collection of all vertices of $C.$ Then we find that $\text {Orb}\ (1) = \{1,2,\cdots, 8 \}.$ If we can find out $\text {Stab}\ (1)$ we are through by orbit-stabilizer theorem. How do I find the stabilizer of $1\ $? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Here it's clear that $Aut(C)$ acts transitively on the vertices. But I don't see how that follows _from_ the fact that each vertex has three neighbors...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich if one of the vertices has fewer or more than $3$ neighbouring points then can we send $1$ to this point? I am a new to this topic. Kindly help me.

Comment: @Anacardium That is a faulty argument for the fact that the group is vertex transitive (it only shows the contrapositive; if the vertices are **not** all the same degree, the group is **not** vertex transitive).

Comment: @MorganRodgers how to argue properly?

Comment: It's easy to _exhibit_ automorphisms that take 1 to any other vertex. A "rotation" gets 2, 3, 4, and following that by the map that swaps "inside" and "outside" takes 1, 2, 3, 4 to 5, 6, 7, 8.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the question, rather the final nail in the coffin of an assertion made in the question: An example of a graph $G$ such that every vertex has degree three but $Aut(G)$ is not transitive.

Not having any graph-drawing software handy: Say the vertices are $(n,0)$ and $(n,2)$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$ and also $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$. Note that when I say we add an edge $(p.q)$ of course we also add the edge $(q,p)$. Add edges $((n,j),(n+1,j))$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$ and $j=0,2$. Add edges $((n,0),(n,2))$ for $n\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0,1\}$. Also edges $((0,0),(0,1)), ((0,1),(0,2)),((1,0),(1,1)), ((1,1),(1,2)), ((0,1),(1,1))$. A bi-infinite ladder with a little extra stuff in the middle of two of the steps.

If I've given the formal definition of the graph I have in mind properly, then the vertex $(0,1)$ has the property that starting there you can traverse exactly five edges and get back to where you started. The vertex $(10,0)$ does not have this property, so $Aut(G)$ is not transitive on vertices.

**Exercise** Give an example of a *finite* graph with the same two properties.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're asking for a finite $3$-regular graph that is not vertex-transitive?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes. One can use the same idea as above, just tying up the loose ends...

Comment: I think I have one with $6$ vertices.  Let the vertices be $1,2,3,4,5,6$ and the edges be $12,23,34,45,56,61,26,35,14.$  If I'm not mistaken, the graph has only one $4$-cycle.

Comment: I think $\text {Stab}\ (1)$ consists of $6$ elements which are $$\left \{\text {id}, (2\ 4)\ (6\ 8), (2\ 5)\ (3\ 8), (3\ 6)\ (4\ 5), (2\ 4\ 5)\ (3\ 8\ 6), (2\ 5\ 4)\ (3\ 6\ 8) \right \}.$$ In other words $$\text {Stab}\ (1) \cong S_3.$$